# How to read single line from an image in Android using Tesseract

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am working on an Android OCR app which reads information from a credit card. Information includes name, card number etc.

When I read text, it returns all the text at a time.

I want to read the second line, i.e. card number only. How can I do that?

Comment: Sir, Actually i have a scanned image of credit card. its formate is as below  
Name: Ibrahim  
ID: AX123  
valid upto: 25th May,2015  

i want read only second line, i.e. ID: AX123, and then in this line, my required information is only AX123. i am not interested in 'ID' tag. How can i do this.

Answer (score 2):

Tesseract does not support any option to select only a part of the recognized text. You can either preprocess the image or post process the extracted text. The first option should be easier and give better results.